# Array of object converting to nesting array

Tags: javascript, arrays

- Root element of the output result is which has the same id and parent_aid. - The next object key id which has parent_id same id to root then it continues in the same manner. - I tried with function but unable to achieve it every time it gives only an object.
- I have added my code and the output i m expecting.

---

```js
let input = [
  {
    'id': "1",
    'parent_aid': "1",
  },
  {
    'id': "2",
    'parent_aid': "1",
  },
  {
    'id': "3",
    'parent_aid': "2",
  },
  {
    'id': "4",
    'parent_aid': "3",
  },
  {
    'id': "5",
    'parent_aid': "4",
  },
  {
    'id': "6",
    'parent_aid': "5",
  },
  {
    'id': "8",
    'parent_aid': "7",
  },
   {
    'id': "7",
    'parent_aid': "6",
  },
  
  {
    'id': "9",
    'parent_aid': "8",
  },
  {
    'id': "10",
    'parent_aid': "9",
  },
  {
    'id': "11",
    'parent_aid': "10",
  },
  {
    'id': "12",
    'parent_aid': "11",
  },
];

// output result should be 
const result = {
  "1": {
    "value": {
      "id": "1",
      "parent_aid": "1"
    },
    "2": {
      "value": {
        "id": "2",
        "parent_aid": "1"
      },
      "3": {
        "value": {
          "id": "3",
          "parent_aid": "2"
        },
        "4": {
          "value": {
            "id": "4",
            "parent_aid": "3"
          },
          "5": {
            "value": {
              "id": "5",
              "parent_aid": "4"
            },
            "6": {
              "value": {
                "id": "6",
                "parent_aid": "5"
              },
              "7": {
                "id": "7",
                "parent_aid": "6"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


let output = {};
let getChildObject = (arr, parentID, obj) => {
  if(!parentID) return;
  return arr.find(val => (val.parent_aid === parentID));

}



const makeNestedObjWithArrayItemsAsKeys = (arr) => {
  let rootIndex = arr.findIndex(val => (val.aid == val.parent_aid));
  let root = arr[rootIndex];
  arr.slice(rootIndex)
  output[root.aid] = { value: root }
  let prev= root.aid;
  for(let i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
    const childObj = getChildObject(arr, prev);
    if(childObj) {
      const value = output[prev];
      let key = childObj['id']
      console.log("ccc",key)
      output[prev][key] = { value: childObj}
      prev = childObj['id'];
    }
  };

  return output
 
};

 makeNestedObjWithArrayItemsAsKeys(input);
```

Comment: Why does the leaf of the desired output not have a `value` property?

Comment: Why does your expected output not have the nodes with id > 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some comments, as I think your example is not correctly defined (missing nodes in the output, and a leaf that does not have a `value` property).

You could use a `map` to store the final nodes, keyed by their `id` value. Then, while iterating the data again, you can build the relationships between those objects and identify the root.

Here is the code:

```js
let input = [{'id': "1",'parent_aid': "1",},{'id': "2",'parent_aid': "1",},{'id': "3",'parent_aid': "2",},{'id': "4",'parent_aid': "3",},{'id': "5",'parent_aid': "4",},{'id': "6",'parent_aid': "5",},{'id': "7",'parent_aid': "6",},];

let map = new Map(input.map(value => [value.id, { value }]));
let root;
for (let {id, parent_aid} of input) {
    if (id !== parent_aid) map.get(parent_aid)[id] = map.get(id);
    else root = { [id]: map.get(id) };
}
console.log(root);
```

Note that in JavaScript objects the properties that are representations of numbers (up to a limit), are iterated/listed before other properties, and so you see that the above snippet outputs the `value` properties after the numerical ones.

Comment: Like a pro!   